# "Congratulations!" covers badge only partially

Tags: bug, profile-page, badge-progress

The clickable badge link is still visible under the "Congratulations!" banner:

[image]

Browser: Google Chrome (54.0.2840.87 m)

Comment: Related: I've reported it in MSO before - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335594/new-privilege-div-broken

Comment: I [cannot reproduce that](http://i.imgur.com/jRYuWJj.png). Chrome 53.0.2785.143 on Linux Mint.

Comment: How shameful of you to use an _arrow_ instead of a freehand circle!